# What is the relation between slave morality and free spirit in Nietzsche's Genealogy of Morality?

Tags: nietzsche, genealogy-of-morals

Considering the discussion on free-spirit by creating its own value system,  how Nietzsche relate "free-spirit" and "slave morality"(its depth and its evilness)?

Comment: See [On the Genealogy of Morality : First Treatise: Good and Evil', 'Good and Bad'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Genealogy_of_Morality#First_Treatise:_%22'Good_and_Evil',_'Good_and_Bad'%22) where "Nietzsche demonstrates that the two opposite pairs "good/evil" and "good/bad" have very different origins, and that the word "good" itself came to represent two opposed meanings. In the "good/bad" distinction, "good" is synonymous with nobility and everything which is powerful and life-asserting;

Comment: in the "good/evil" distinction, which Nietzsche calls "slave morality", the meaning of "good" is made the antithesis of the original aristocratic "good", which itself is re-labelled "evil". "

Comment: There are two kinds of morality acc. to Nietzsche, "Slave morality" and "Master morality". Then  "good / bad" and "good / evil" distinctions come to play. But there is an another group, "free spirit" . They are seperated themselves from the tension of the moral values of the dominate group. My question is: what kind of person are they? They have free spirits but to have a free spirit, you have to gain it. How this group gain their freedom?

Comment: But N is not completly aligning itself with *free spirits*, because "all these pale atheists, Antichrists, immoralists, nihilists, these skeptics" have not become truly “free” from the counter-natural tradition of the ascetic ideal. These modern figures “are very far from being free spirits: because they still believe in truth.” [see Essay Three, §24].